# Pb with duration Atom auto-save and live-server

Tags: delay, atom-editor, autosave, liveserver

I'm new on Atom, and I would like to know if it's possible to set the auto-save duration to 1 second.
I can't launch the live server either. Can you help me ?
Thanks a lot in advance !
See you soon,
Eric.

I searched the GitHub documentation, StackOverFlow and the internet, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: [Please ask only one question at a time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/248627)

Comment: OK Chris.... I am so sorry.
I beg your pardon.